# How run query in two different model/controllers and then merge pagination in node.js using mongoose pagination?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I have **two different models** -

1. `articleModel.js` (which is used by `mainController.js`, for sending req and showing data)
2. `sqModel.js` (which is used by `fulltextController.js`, receives req and sends res).

Now I am trying to **send some requests to fulltextController.js** and **get a response in mainController.js**
on fulltext.js there is some **query running that is using** `sqModel.js` and main.js using `articleModel.js`, when I receive a response in terms of ids, I run some matching operations into main.js and show data to the frontend. Now the problem is pagination is not working between the two of them, how can I handle or merge pagination between them?

**fulltextController.js (where query runs and sends a response, using sqModel.js)**

```
  const searchModel = require("../model/sqModel.js");

const getArticles = (req, res) => {
  const _searchKeyword = req.body.groupkeyword;
  const keywords = _searchKeyword
    .match(/"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"|[^ ]+/g)
    .map((kw) => kw.replace(/"/g, ""))
    .map((kw) => kw.toUpperCase());
  const clientid = req.body.clientid;
  const page = parseInt(req.body.page || 1);
  const perpage = parseInt(req.body.perpage) || 10;
  // Validate page and limit parameters
  if (isNaN(page) || page < 1) {
    page = 1;
  }
  if (isNaN(perpage) || perpage < 1 || perpage > 100) {
    perpage = 10;
  }

  let agg;
 

  if (keywords.length === 1) {
    agg = [
      {
        $search: {
          index: "fulltext",
          compound: {
            must: [
              {
                text: {
                  query: clientid,
                  path: ["clientidArray"],
                },
              },
              {
                text: {
                  query: keywords[0],
                  path: ["headline", "subtitle", "fulltext"],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          articleid: 1,
          _id: 0,
        },
      },

      {
        $skip: (page - 1) * perpage, // calculate the number of documents to skip
      },
      {
        $limit: perpage, // limit the number of documents to return per page
      },
    ];
  } else {
  
    console.log("No Data!");

 
  }

  searchModel.aggregate(agg, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500);
    } else {
      const _articleids = data.map((x) => x.articleid);

      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ articleids: _articleids, page: page, perpage: perpage });
    }
  });
};
module.exports = {
  getArticles,
};
```

**MainController.js (where I receive res and use articleModel.js)**

```
    var articlesModule = require("../model/ArticleModel1.js");
  const searchModel = require("../model/sqModel.js");
  var articlepost = (req, res) => {
    let page = req.body.page ? req.body.page : 1;
  
    let perpage = req.body.perpage ? req.body.perpage : 100;
  var options = {
    page: parseInt(req.body.page, 10) || 1,
    limit: parseInt(req.body.perpage, 10) || 100,
  };
  if (req.body.fullTextKeyword != "") {
    //FullText Search
    let _fullText = req.body.fullTextKeyword;
    request.post(
      {
        url: "http://localhost:3000/search/getarticles",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          groupkeyword: _fullText,
          fdate: todate,
          tdate: fromdate,
          page: req.body.page,
          perpage: req.body.perpage,
          clientid: req.body.clientid,
        },
        json: true,
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        query.articleid = {
          $in: body.articleids, //where in condition
        };
        options.page = parseInt(req.body.page, 10) || options.page; // update page option
        options.limit = parseInt(req.body.perpage, 10) || options.limit; // update perpage option
        articlesModule.paginate(query, options, function (err, impacts) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error 2" + err);
            res.status(500);
            res.send("internal error");
          } else {
            res.status(200);
            console.log("sending data");
            res.json(impacts);
          }
        });
      }
    );
  } else {
    options.page = parseInt(req.body.page, 10) || options.page; // update page option
    options.limit = parseInt(req.body.perpage, 10) || options.limit; // update perpage option
    articlesModule.paginate(query, options, function (err, impacts) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error 2" + err);
        res.status(500);
        res.send("internal error");
      } else {
        res.status(200);
        console.log("sending data");
        res.json(impacts);
      }
    });
  }
};

module.exports = { 
  articlepost: articlepost 
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!